# Running NodeJs http-server forever with PM2

Tags: node.js, httpserver, pm2

My question is about running HTTP-server in combination with PM2.

The problem I face is that:

1. HTTP-server requires as input a folder which is the root of the website and a port number to run the website on.
2. PM2 doesn't recognize the HTTP-server command, even when HTTP-server is installed with the `-g` option.

So I tried the following (note the double dash which should pass the parameters to the HTTP-server script:

```
/node_modules/http-server/lib$ pm2 start http-server.js -- /home/unixuser/websiteroot -p8686
```

But it doesn't work.

I also tried:

```
http-server /home/unixuser/websiteroot -p8686
```

Which does work, but doesn't have the great support of pm2 ?

Any suggestions would be great, thanks!

Comment: you can go to your build path and hit:build/prod$ sudo pm2 start /usr/local/bin/http-server -p 8080

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You almost had it.

Check where http-server is located by executing:

```
$ which http-server
```

You should get something like this `/usr/bin/http-server`

Then `cd` to the directory you want to serve files from and execute:

```
$ pm2 start /usr/bin/http-server --name my-file-server -- -p 8080 -d false
```

`--name my-file-server` is optional, but `--` is required to pass arguments through to the `http-server` command.

Comment: You will often have multiple versions/installations of the same executable on the same machine and `which` is handy to see which one is linked to the command.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `--` to pass arguments to http-server, i came for that

Comment: Or do in one go `pm2 start $(which http-server) --name my-file-server -- -p 8080 -d false`. No need to manually which, copy and cd.

Answer (score 11):

```
pm2 start <location>/http-server --name http-server -- -p <port> -d false
```

or

PM2 modules it self has in-build static file to be served, which is similar to http-server
https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/expose/

```
pm2 serve <path> <port>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
pm2 start 'http-server-spa websiteroot index.html 8080'
```

Answer (score 0):

if we have a build generated by grunt,then go to its path and hit:

```
~/app/build/prod$ sudo pm2 start /usr/local/bin/http-server -p 8080
```

Now check app status at `localhost:8080`