# Access file created by NodeJS module using PHP or browser

Tags: php, node.js, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed a [NodeJS module](https://github.com/drawrowfly/tiktok-scraper) on a Digital Ocean Droplet. It generates a csv file that I store in the directory `root/csv_file/my_file.csv`.

However, I cannot access it in the browser by simply visiting `ip_address/csv_file/my_file.csv`.

I [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333790/node-js-quick-file-server-static-files-over-http) which asks me to install `http-server` so I installed it. After that I ran the following command:

```
http-server csv_file
```

and

```
http-server root
```

However, none of the allowed me to access the file by visiting `root/csv_file/my_file.csv`.

Using the `file_get_contents()` function in PHP gives me the following error:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

How can I access this file preferably in PHP or in browser?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http-server csv_file` will serve in port 8080 by default.
Did you try http://your_ip_address:8080
Please make sure: the port is already opened/allowed (https://askubuntu.com/questions/911765/open-port-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Thanks Thang. :) Will I have to always run `http-server csv_file` in console before I can access the file in browser or using PHP?

Comment: Thanks Thang. Just one more question. :)  Will I have to **always** run `http-server csv_file` in the terminal before I can access the file in browser ?

Comment: yes, have to run it to serve your files. But It will be turned off when you close your terminal or exit. Please use `pm2` to keep it alive. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804966/running-nodejs-http-server-forever-with-pm2
it will take some time to know `pm2`, but `pm2` is really great for nodejs apps